# Qt C++ QNetworkRequest - FollowRedirectsAttribute не работает с QHttpMultiPart* и QIODevice*

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkrequest

Какая-то странная логика у QtNetwork.

Видимо, `QNetworkAccessManager` считает, что при отправке запроса и получение ответа `302 Redirect` совсем не надо отправлять те же данные, что были переданы в `QHttpMultiPart*` или `QIODevice*` ещё раз, достаточно просто отправить заново этот же запрос по новому адресу с пустым телом запроса.

Приблизительно так это выглядит при ПЕРВОМ запросе

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: https://example.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Content-Length: 123

ДАННЫЕ ДЛЯ ОТПРАВКИ С ПОМОЩЬЮ QIODevice* / QHttpMultiPart*
```

А вот так при редиректе (302):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: https://example.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Content-Length: 0
    
(****А ТУТ УЖЕ ПУСТО****)
```

> Из-за того, что `QNetworkAccessManager` читает из буфера `QIODevice*` с помощью `readAll()`
> при редиректе этот буфер уже пуст и, следовательно, отправлять больше
> нечего. Это баг? Что с этим можно сделать, чтобы не страдать?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему переопределением `QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest` простым сохранением данных в переменную и повторную отравку запроса. Работает без проблем:

```
QNetworkReply *NetworkAccessManager::createRequest(QNetworkAccessManager::Operation op,
                                                        const QNetworkRequest &request, QIODevice *outgoingData)
{
    if (outgoingData) {
        if (outgoingData->atEnd()) {
            QScopedPointer<QBuffer> buffer(new QBuffer);

            buffer->setData(lastData);
            buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

            //outgoingData->deleteLater(); Будем считать, что удалением основного QIODevice*
            //                             экземпляра должен заниматься пользователь,
            //                             так как о редиректе он ничего не знает
            return QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(op, request, buffer.take());
        }
        else {
            lastData = outgoingData->readAll();
            return createRequest(op, request, outgoingData);
        }
    }
    return QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(op, request);
}
```